# Can't install .NET 4.0 - error code 1406.

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-framework, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to install .NET framework 4.0 under Windows 7 but am getting an error with code 1406.

I checked the logs:

```
MSI (C:\a002a771e38ece7cca\netfx_Core_x64.msi) Installation failed.  
Msi Log: Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Setup_20121229_020733440-MSI_netfx_Core_x64.msi.txt
Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x80070643),  
"Fatal error during installation. " (Elapsed time: 0 00:02:15).
```

It all started with a cleanup tool for removing .NET 4.5 since I was trying to get rid of a linker error that it might have caused. However, after cleaning it up, I couldn't run both VS2010 and VS2012. Then, I uninstalled both IDE's and tried to install VS2010. That failed since I couldn't install .NET 4.0.

I really feel helpless and don't want to reinstall the whole OS from scratch. So what should I do?

Comment: Who knows what sort of mess that cleanup tool caused in your system's registry? That's why one should stay away from automated system/registry cleaners most of the time. What does the MSI Log say? See if [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976982) helps. You can also try renaming the `Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly` dir before attempting a reinstall of .NET 4.0

Comment: @Karan, Yes, that's absolutely true. Never again. However, I was lucky since I was able to reinstall VS2012, and it fixed .net 4.0 and 4.5, and then installed VS2010, now both are fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the contents of `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework` but not the folder itself.
2. If step1 did not work, follow [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/astebner/solving-setup-errors-by-using-the-subinacl-tool-to-repair-file-and-registry-permissions) guide.

Credits: http://blogs.msdn.com

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on Windows 7 Ultimate N x64, when I was installing a Framework 4.0 security update.

For me, the root cause was that I did not have System.Xml.Serialization.xml in my Framework 4.0 folders, for whatever reason.

I had another Windows 7 x64 machine, so I copied the files from there:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Xml.Serialization.dll and
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Xml.Serialization.dll

(I think they're the same file, actually).

Reran it, and it worked like a charm.